# Одновременное чтение файла и запись в него

Tags: c#

Есть 2 текстовых файла. 1 поток читает по строкам инфу из файл(1) и дописывает в файл(2), 2 поток так же по строкам читает инфу из файл(2) и дописывает ее в файл(1). По сути нужно ,чтобы программа выполнялась бесконечно, поскольку до конца файлов не получится дойти. Но сейчас streamReader читает файлы так, как будто они не меняются в ходе выполнения программы, хотя по ее(программы) завершению в файлы дописывается инфо из другого (только по 1 разу для каждого файла)
Вот такой код у меня сейчас. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace l6_1
{

class Program
{
    public static string file1 = "D:/l6sharp/1.txt";
    public static string file2 = "D:/l6sharp/2.txt";
    private static FileStream filestream1;
    private static FileStream filestream2;
    private static StreamReader f1r;
    private static StreamReader f2r;
    private static StreamWriter f1w;
    private static StreamWriter f2w;

    static void from1to2()
    {
        string line;
        while (true)
        {

            if ((line = f1r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                f2w.WriteLine(line);
                f2w.Flush();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    static void from2to1()
    {
        string line;
        while (true)
        {

            if ((line = f2r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                f1w.WriteLine(line);
                f1w.Flush();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        filestream1 = new System.IO.FileStream(file1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        filestream2 = new System.IO.FileStream(file2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        f1r = new StreamReader(filestream1);
        f2r = new StreamReader(filestream2);
        f1w = new StreamWriter(filestream1);
        f2w = new StreamWriter(filestream2);
        Task task1 = new Task(from1to2);
        Task task2 = new Task(from2to1);
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Что-то у вас не видно кода сохранения и восстановления файловых указателей...

Comment: Если вы про позицию указателя в файле, то разве это имеет значение? Ведь новая информация дописывается в конец файла

Comment: Скорее всего имеет. Функции типа ReadFile из информации о файле принимают на вход только хэндл, и вероятно, позиции привязаны к хэндлу. Операции чтения и записи указатель перемещают в итоге один поток меняет его для всех остальных. Ради интереса можете смещения после каждой операции выводить.

Comment: StreamReader скорее всего буферизирует считанный файл. Так что если размер файла меньше размера буфера, он StreamReader просто в начале считает весь файл в память, и всё.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3791142/276994

Comment: Спасибо, дело действительно было в том, что при чтении и записи указатель главного потока файла смещался не так, как ожидалось. Добавил сохранение позиции, с которой последний раз проводилось чтение, теперь работает тка, как и должно)

Comment: если вы нашли решение добавьте его в ответ, чтобы вопрос не "висел" не отвеченным.

Comment: Да, добавьте ответ если считаете вопрос полезным, если вопрос не очень полезный - удалите его.

Answer (score 1):

Как отметил VladD,

> StreamReader скорее всего буферизирует считанный файл. Так что если
>   размер файла меньше размера буфера, он StreamReader просто в начале
>   считает весь файл в память, и всё.

Andrew:

> при чтении и записи указатель главного потока файла смещался не так,
>   как ожидалось. Добавил сохранение позиции, с которой последний раз
>   проводилось чтение, теперь работает тка, как и должно)